# Add shortcut/hot keys for forms being loaded in panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `MainForm` containing a panel which is being used to load an(y)other form.
This is how I am doing it.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    panel3.Controls.Clear();
    AnotherForm anotherForm = new AnotherForm();
    anotherForm.TopLevel = false;
    anotherForm.Location = new Point(anotherForm.Location.X, anotherForm.Location.Y);
    panel3.Controls.Add(anotherForm);
    anotherForm.Show();
}
```

Now I want to add shortcuts to activate certain `textboxes`, but the code is just not working. This is what I have tried and is working under regular conditions (not being opened inside a panel)

```
private void AnotherForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "A")
        MessageBox.Show("asdf");
}
```

Also, the framework is 4.5. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by *the code is just not working*. What happens after running this code? What's your desired result?

Comment: Nothing happens when the code is running is what happens. It won't even goto the event handler while debugging. I want to show the messagebox when a certain key is pressed.

Comment: OK. Just check out my answer below. Hope it helps.

Comment: @S.Akbari. Done.

Answer (score 0):

The `Forms` are not responding to `KeyDown` event, until their [`KeyPreview`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Form_KeyPreview) property is set to `true`. So you need to set the `AnotherForm`'s `KeyPreview` property to true:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.

Also in order to make this works you need to force the form focus by calling the `Focus` method after `Application.OpenForms` like this::

```
...
panel1.Controls.Add(anotherForm);
anotherForm.Show();
Application.OpenForms[anotherForm.Name]?.Focus();
```

Comment: Since OP need to load `AnotherForm` (which is not top-level window) into MainForm panel, set `KeyPreview` to true will not help. That's why I've removed my comment.. Probably to solve this, we need to override `ProcessCmdKey`

Comment: @Luthfay He would like to handle `KeyDown` of `AnotherForm` and without setting the `KeyPreview` property, this will not be done and it has nothing to do with loading the form inside another form's panel I think.

Comment: @S.Akbari, its not working. Despite `KeyPreview` property having been set to true.

Comment: @fasihullahkhan What do you mean by it's not working. I have reproduced your issue in my environment and it is working fine for me. Could you please provide more details.

Comment: I just tried this however it seems doesn't work. Then i try to overriding `ProcessCmdKey` and I still got no desired result. @fasihullahkhan I'm pretty sure you need to make `AnotherForm` focused. For example, if you have button inside `AnotherForm`, call button.Focus() inside `AnotherForm`'s constructor.

Comment: @S.Akbari, Sure. What more details would you like to have?

Comment: @fasihullahkhan Take a look at this: https://media.giphy.com/media/biOkR4iOgdZrptBSo8/giphy.gif Before button at `AnotherForm` focused, `KeyPress` doesn't work. So i think you need to make some control inside `AnotherForm` focused.

Comment: @fasihullahkhan Define what is not working. As I said already, I have reproduced your issue and it's no working fine for me. So describe what happens step by step!

Comment: @Luthfay, seems like you are getting me. However, I just called a `btnSearch.Focus();` under `InitializeComponent();`, still its not working. I have to click inside a TextBox or a Button first for the shortcut work.

Comment: @S.Akbari, `KeyDown` handler is not being triggered.

Comment: @Luthfay, yes. That's exactly what is happening.

Comment: @fasihullahkhan I just get what is your problem. Yes as Luthfay alreay pointed out you need to focus a control on your `AnotherForm` firstly in order to make this works. Since I have already did this, It was working for me. This is why I was confused that you were stating it doesn't work. I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: @S.Akbari, where should I use this? `Application.OpenForms[anotherForm.Name]?.Focus();`

Comment: @fasihullahkhan Check my new update. Just after your code.

Comment: `Application.OpenForms` Nice one, unthinkable :D